# Max Date in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-grid

I have a date column in an Editable Grid in Kendo UI. How can I set the Max Date in the DatePicker to a custom date.

```
var objdataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        batch: true,
        data:viewModel,
        pageSize: 20,
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "BatchGrid",
                fields: {
                    EDATE: {
                        editable: true, type: 'date'
                },//Column 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't do it from the datasource, however you can change it inside the columns declaration within your kendo grid.

```
 columns:
        [
            {
                field: "EventDate",
                title: "Date",
                format: "{0:dd MMM yyyy}",
                width: 200,
                filterable: {
                    extra: false,
                    messages: { info: "" },
                    operators: {
                        date: {
                            gte: "From",
                            lte: "To"
                        }
                    },
                    ui: function(element) {
                        element.kendoDatePicker({
                            max: new Date()
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
```